# Node.js how to handle packet fragmentation with net.Server

Tags: node.js, tcp

When a net.Server receives data that exceeds 1500 bytes (default mtu), the 'on data' event is executed with each fragment of the packet. Is there a way to receive the whole packet in a single 'on data' call?

Thanks.

Comment: Why ? Just concatenate the chunks if you need it in one piece.

Comment: There are hundred of sources sending data, the source_id is in the begin of packet. If a packet is fragmented, I can't identify the source of the following chunks.

Comment: Can you show your code ? Usually you work on sockets, you don't handle packets just like this...

Comment: The code is too large. The socket passed to "onconnection" event have to handle several event types. I can't simply concatenate the events after receive them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var sys     = require('sys');
var net     = require('net');;

var socktimeout = 600000;
var svrport = your_port;

var svr = net.createServer(function(sock) {
  var mdata = new Buffer(0);
    //sys.puts('Connected: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort); 
     sock.setTimeout(socktimeout,function(){
            sock.end("timeout");
            sock.destroy();
        });

    sock.on('data', function(data) {  


        if(mdata.length != 0)
        {
          var tempBuf = Buffer.concat([mdata, data]);
          mdata = tempBuf;
        }
        else
        {
          mdata = data;
        }

        var len=got_your_Packget_length(mdata);
         
      if(mdata.length == len)
      {
        do_your_job(mdata)
        mdata = new Buffer(0);
      }


    });
 


    sock.on('error', function(err) { // Handle the connection error.
        sys.puts('error: ' + err +'\n');
    });
});
 
svr.listen(svrport);
```

Comment: I believe this is useless if you got no idea how large the data package is. I think it should be possible to check the datagram's ethernet fragment length, frag_flag and offset. For a better understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999739/ip-fragmentation-and-reassembly